# Facilitação nos projetos com PHP

Tags: php, sublime-text

Eu trabalho com PHP utilizando o Sublime Text e gostaria de algo semelhante a como é no Eclipse. Por exemplo:

No Eclipse consigo abrir exatamente onde o método foi declarado. No Sublime Text não encontrei nenhuma opção semelhante, que eu uso o atalho CTRL + clique do mouse para abrir declarações de método e tudo mais.

O Sublime Text tem alguma opção que facilite a navegação do meu projeto, para verificar as declarações dos métodos/funções?

Comment: Por padrão no Sublime, se tu ficar com o mouse em cima do nome do método ou variável ele irá exibir um popup com o caminho da declaração dele, basta clicar no caminho e pronto.

Answer (score 13):

> A maior parte do conteúdo aqui **"talvez"** só se aplique ao Sublime Text 3, note que Sublime Text 2 foi atualizado pela última vez em [8 de Julho 2013](https://sublimetext.com/2)

Para PHP assim como para outras linguagens o plugin que funciona muito é o CodeIntel, ele usa o autocomplete enquanto digita, assim não precisa de comandos. Ele reconhece funções, classes e namespaces customizados (criados no seu projeto), mesmo que esteja em um arquivo diferente.

1. Instale o SublimeCodeIntel <kbd>Preferences</kbd> > <kbd>Package Control</kbd> > <kbd>Install Package</kbd>
2. Digite `SublimeCodeIntel`, e selecione ele para instalar
3. Instale o PhpIntel <kbd>Preferences</kbd> > <kbd>Package Control</kbd> > <kbd>Install Package</kbd>
4. Digite `PhpIntel`, e selecione ele para instalar

Agora você deve selecionar a pasta do seu projeto e arrastar para o SublimeText, assim:

[image: projeto no sublimetext]

Agora pelo proprio sublime navegue nos arquivos do projeto, abra qualquer arquivo e aperte <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>, o CodeIntel vai demorar um pouco na primeira vez, mas vai gerar na pasta do teu projeto uma outra pasta chamada `.phpintel`, nela contém um mapeamento e caches das suas classes, toda vez que usar <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> ele vai atualizar isto, então depois é só testar:

[image: Classes customizadas]

Veja que o namespace e classe não são nativos, apesar que ele reconhece nativos do PHP também.

---

### Outras dicas

Outras configurações interessantes que pode levar em consideração é editar o Settings, vá até <kbd>Preferences</kbd> > <kbd>Settings</kbd>, vai abrir uma janela com dois documentos, edite somente o da direita, segue algumas configurações que pode usar:

Remove os espaços desnecessários ao salvar:

```
"trailing_spaces_trim_on_save": true,
```

Troca os TABs por espaços:

```
"translate_tabs_to_spaces": true,
```

Usa TABs como 4 espaços, você pode ajustar aqui:

```
"tab_size": 4,
```

Mostra a codificação do arquivo atual no rodapé do SublimeText, ajuda a evitar muitas dores de cabeça:

```
"show_encoding": true,
```

As quebras de linha usam apenas `LF`:

```
"default_line_ending": "unix",
```

Mostra qual tipo de "nova linha" usa, por exemplo: `Unix` (se as linhas no documento terminarem em `LF`) ou `Windows` (se as linhas no documento terminarem em `CR LF`):

```
"show_line_endings": true,
```

Adiciona quebra de linha no final do documento se necessário (claro que isto é opcional):

```
"ensure_newline_at_eof_on_save": true,
```

Deve ficar parecido com isto:

```
{
    "always_show_minimap_viewport": true,
    "bold_folder_labels": true,
    "font_size": 11,
    "highlight_line": true,
    "ignored_packages":
    [
        "Vintage"
    ],
    "indent_guide_options":
    [
        "draw_normal",
        "draw_active"
    ],
    "line_padding_bottom": 3,
    "line_padding_top": 3,
    "overlay_scroll_bars": "enabled",
    "show_encoding": true,
    "tab_size": 4,
    "trailing_spaces_trim_on_save": true,
    "translate_tabs_to_spaces": true,
    "show_encoding": true,
    "show_line_endings": true,
    "ensure_newline_at_eof_on_save": true,
    "word_wrap": true
}
```

---

### Extra

Corretor ortográfico, não tem relação, mas um corretor ortográfico pode ajudar a evitar constrangimentos as vezes, no caso você pode instalar manualmente ele, o que pode ser algo bem complexo, eu mesmo tentei baixar o `.dic` do LibreOffice e deu problema com *Unicode*, então acabei por copiar `.dic` que havia na pasta do Firefox, mas esse é um pouco complicado, então vou lhe indicar do repositório mesmo, selecione o idioma de preferencia em https://github.com/titoBouzout/Dictionaries e baixe o .dic e o .aff, por exemplo:

- https://github.com/titoBouzout/Dictionaries/blob/master/Portuguese%20(Brazilian).dic
- https://github.com/titoBouzout/Dictionaries/blob/master/Portuguese%20(Brazilian).aff

Abra a pasta dos pacotes, se for Linux ou Mac:

- `~/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages`

Se for Windows talvez seja a pasta assim `SublimeText\Data\Packages\`

Crie uma pasta chamada `Portuguese` por exemplo e copie ambos arquivos nela, talvez tenha que fechar o sublime e abrir novamente, então vá até <kbd>View</kbd> > <kbd>Dictionary</kbd> e veja se aparece `Portuguese`, ou pode apontar pelo Settings também, assim:

```
"dictionary": "Packages/Portuguese/Portuguese (Brazilian).dic",
```

E habilite o corretor ortográfico permanentemente:

```
"spell_check": true,
```

Deve ficar mais ou menos assim:

```
{
    "always_show_minimap_viewport": true,
    "bold_folder_labels": true,
    "dictionary": "Packages/Portuguese/Portuguese (Brazilian).dic",
    "font_size": 11,
    "highlight_line": true,
    "ignored_packages":
    [
        "Vintage"
    ],
    "indent_guide_options":
    [
        "draw_normal",
        "draw_active"
    ],
    "line_padding_bottom": 3,
    "line_padding_top": 3,
    "overlay_scroll_bars": "enabled",
    "show_encoding": true,
    "spell_check": true,
    "tab_size": 4,
    "trailing_spaces_trim_on_save": true,
    "translate_tabs_to_spaces": true,
    "show_encoding": true,
    "show_line_endings": true,
    "ensure_newline_at_eof_on_save": true,
    "word_wrap": true
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Trabalho com Sublime Text também. Na versão que eu uso, a 3 (a sua provavelmente é a mesma), basta passar o mouse sobre uma função e esperar 1 a 2 segundos que um pequeno pop-up com uma lista de arquivos contendo a função aparece no cursor. Se o Sublime não achar nenhum arquivo com essa função ele não aparece. Não fui atrás de configurá-lo, mas talvez tenha alguma coisa para isso. Mas até onde eu sei só funciona com funções.

Answer (score 2):

Existe o pacote PHPIntel que traz funções de go to declaration colocando o ponteiro sobre o método/Classe e apertando ctrl + f5

https://packagecontrol.io/packages/PHPIntel

Comment: Todos os plug-ins que testei não funcionaram corretamente. O SublimeCodeIntel estava dando timeout direto quando eu tentava abrir onde a função foi declarada.

O PHPIntel testamos em equipe aqui, mas não chegou a nem funcionar. Testamos com outros atalhos, reconfigurar e nada deu certo.

Alguém tem mais alguma ideia? Realmente é importante isso pra mim.

Comment: @GuilhermeNass eu instalei recentemente e não houve problemas, o PHPIntel como eu expliquei na resposta só funciona se tiver o CodeIntel, as ideias do passo a passo estão todos na resposta que formulei, se o timeout está ocorrendo pode ser a sua rede que tem algum bloqueio ou problema no download.

Comment: Entendi @GuilhermeNascimento...

Eu estou utilizando o Sublime Text 2, funciona normalmente também né?

Comment: @GuilhermeNass nunca usei Sublimetext2 não vejo motivos para usar o 2 sendo que o 3 já está tão bom.