# Ao alterar qualquer linha do PHP, dá erro 500 (servidor)

Tags: php, linux, servidor

Colegas.

Estou com sérios problemas com um determinado servidor, do qual só com ele acontece esses erros. Temos um sistema do qual mudamos o diretório e todos os links estao funcionando perfeitamente e estão no diretório raiz do servidor. Mudamos de 2016, para 2017, porém há duas semanas para cá, qualquer linha que mexemos ou até mesmo comentamos, dá erro 500,a ponto de excluirmos todo o código e deixar somente:

```
<?php
echo "OK";
?>
```

Após inúmeras pesquisas, deparei-me com um fórum onde pediu para abrir o Notepad++, visualizar todos os caracteres e observar se o código aparece LF, podendo aparecer também LF e CR. As páginas do diretório antigo aparece dessa forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E no diretório novo onde migramos o sistema e está dando esse problema:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como posso corrigir isso? O servidor onde estão alocados os arquivos é Linux.

Comment: Alguma linha a respeito no error_log?

Comment: Parece um erro de codificação. Não tenho certeza más tente criar um arquivo novo para testar porque pode ser a codificação utilizada ao criar com um editor esta conflitando com um novo editor (ou codificação diferente no mesmo editor). Se um novo arquivo (só para teste) criado em um editor com codificação `UTF-8` rodar esta ai o problema do contrário pode ser o `PHP` ou no sistema.

Comment: Você esta subindo os arquivos via FTP?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Este `CR` significa *carriage return* e `LF` significa *line feed*, o `LF` é usado para gerar "novas linhas" (quebra de linha), o `CR` até o *Mac 9* era usado como quebra de linha, mas a partir do 10 (*Mac OS X*) passou a usar `LF`, creio que hoje todos sistemas internamente usem apenas `LF`, somente o editor do Windows *notepad.exe* ainda salva e lê quebras de linhas assim "`CR`+`LF`" (formado por ambos), talvez seja por retrocompatibilidade, de fato isto não afeta em nada desde que `LF` esteja presente logo após o `CR`.

O que suponho é que teu script ao editar e salvar estar sumindo com o `LF` porque esta usando alguma configuração no *notepad++*, outra possibilidade é de você estar subindo os arquivos via *FTP* com alguma configuração que esteja falhando, também pode ser porque se o upload estiver em ASCII as vezes pode ocorrer perda de caracteres (se houver no meio do arquivo algum caractere não suportado).

> Note que não estou afirmando que o `CR` seja a falha no servidor Linux, mas creio que pode ser direta ou indiretamente, tanto que em meu Debian (um tipo de Linux) funcionou normalmente usando apenas `CR`, ou seja pode ser que o `CR` junto a outro caractere é que cause a falha como pode ser outro caractere que ficou perdido sem qualquer relação com o `CR`

### Notepad++

Abra no *notepad++* <kbd>Settings</kbd> > <kbd>Preferences</kbd> > <kbd>New document</kbd> > <kbd>Format (Line ending)</kbd>, assim:

[image: new line]

Veja se esta selecionado `CR LF` ou `LF` ou `CR`, provavelmente deve estar `CR`, se estiver troque por `LF` ou `CR LF`, claro que isto talvez não resolva o problema dos arquivos que já foram editados, então para corrigir isto, faça o seguinte no notepad++:

- Faça um backup de todos documentos
- Abra todos arquivos que pretende editar, que não sejam do backup de modo que fiquem em abas assim:

[image: abas]

Então aperte <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> e deverá aparecer algo assim:

[image: replace]

- Selecione a opção `Extended (\n, \r, \t, \0, \x)`

Agora iremos trocar todos `CR` e `CR+LF` por `LF` apenas

- Digite em *Find what*: `\r\l` (para evitar conflito nos próximos passos)
- Digite em *Replace with*: `\l`
- Aperte o botão *Replace All in All Opened Documents*
- Digite em *Find what*: `\r`
- Digite em *Replace with*: `\l`
- Aperte o botão *Replace All in All Opened Documents*

Neste caso usei apenas o `LF` que já basta para o caso, mas pode fazer assim (acaso queira `CR LF`):

- Digite em *Find what*: `\r\l` (para evitar conflito nos próximos passos)
- Digite em *Replace with*: `\r`
- Aperte o botão *Replace All in All Opened Documents*
- Digite em *Find what*: `\r`
- Digite em *Replace with*: `\r\l`
- Aperte o botão *Replace All in All Opened Documents*

Selecione no notepad++ a opção <kbd>File</kbd> > <kbd>Save All</kbd> (ou <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>), pronto agora as coisas devem estar concertadas, ainda se falhar é porque provavelmente esta usando FTP, neste caso siga o próximo passo:

### FTP

Se estiver usando *FTP Filezilla* ou semelhante talvez o upload via ASCII esteja fazendo algum caractere conflitar e algo se perder, pode também ser alguma configuração do proprio FTP, se for o Filezilla vá até <kbd>Edit</kbd> > <kbd>Settings...</kbd> > <kbd>Transfer</kbd> > <kbd>File Types</kbd>:

[image: filezilla]

Em Default transfer type troque de <kbd>Auto</kbd> ou <kbd>ASCII</kbd> para <kbd>Binary</kbd> e aperte <kbd>Ok</kbd>, em seguida tente fazer o upload novamente e veja se esta passou a funcionar.

### Extra

Pessoalmente para trabalhar com PHP, apesar de ser algo totalmente opcional, eu prefiro o SublimeText, desde que bem configurado, se tiver algum interesse aqui deixei algumas dicas:

- [Facilitação nos projetos com PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/193364/3635)

Comment: Perfeito Guilherme Nascimento. Muito obrigado pelos esclarecimentos.