# Problemas no "Hello, world!" em PHP

Tags: php, apache, xampp

Parece piada, mas é fato. Eu fiz meu primeiro código em PHP e o testei, mas não saiu o que eu esperava. Veja a imagem com as janelas dos programas usados nesse teste.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Em resumo, não sei porque ao invés de imprimir `1st > HW` ele imprimiu `HW"; ?>` no chrome. Parece até que ele interpreta `<?php echo "1st >` como um código desconhecido e imprime o que segue adiante.

Adicionalmente, testei no internet explorer e ele apenas apresenta o código do arquivo, não o executa. Afinal alguém pode me explicar o que fiz de errado neste "hello world"?

Comment: Seu Xampp esta bem desatualizado (aparentemente), a versão que esta usando é de 2015, talvez você tenha baixado uma versão de uma fonte antiga ou problemática ou talvez seja um computador antigo do qual você mexeu em algo que fez o PHP parar de funcionar no Apache. De qualquer recomendo que instale do link https://www.apachefriends.org/pt_br/index.html

Comment: Ou, no mínimo, desconfigurado, pois o Apache parece não estar interpretando seu arquivo com o PHP. Se acessar o código fonte da página, verá que o código PHP está lá da maneira que escreveu.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ou você desconfigurou o Apache no `httpd.conf` (pois essa versão que usa do Xampp é antiga, pode ser que você tenha feito isso e não se recorda), ou você no *nodepad.exe* salvou o documento como `Unicode` ou `Unicode big endian`:

[image: notepad save as]

Essa codificação não vai funcionar, salve os documentos como *ANSI* e então deverá trabalhar normalmente.

Eu mesmo fiz o teste, salvei como `Unicode big endian` em um documento com o seguinte conteúdo:

> Testei também `Unicode` e ocorreu o mesmo

```
Teste: <?php echo 'oi'; ?>
```

e testei:

> [image: Unicode big endian]

Ao abrir o *view-source* é exibido isto:

> [image: view-source do Unicode big endian]

Ou seja o interpretador do PHP não consegue entender como se fosse ANSI (ou "aproximado"), após salvar como *ANSI* testei novamente e funcionou:

> [image: ANSI]

### Alternativas ao nodepad.exe

O Notepad.exe é bem limitado, hoje temos alternativas que podem lhe atender melhor como o:

- Notepad++: https://notepad-plus-plus.org
- SublimeText: https://www.sublimetext.com

Deixei algumas **sugestões** de configurações o SublimeText com PHP:

- [Facilitação nos projetos com PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/193364/3635) (sugestões para trabalhar com Sublimetext e php)
- [Dúvida com charset=iso-8859-1 e utf8](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/43205/3635) (como configurar para usar UTF-8 ou outra configuração)

Comment: Tem razão. O erro está na configuração de caracter do arquivo de texto. Não pode escolher unicode. Mas então a acentuação fica dificultada, pelo que estou vendo. É uma pena. Obrigado pela resposta.

Comment: @RHERWOLF sobre os acentos com Unicode, leia o link que deixei na resposta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/43205/3635, salve o documento com "UTF-8 sem BOM", configure o header, configure a conexão mysql (se estiver usando). Recomendo que use Notepad++ ou SublimeText, com eles você vai conseguir trabalhar melhor e com as dicas que lhe passei vai conseguir usar a acentuação.